# When i start Weblogic after building the project, the build folder getting to cleaned

Tags: java, maven, build, weblogic, target

I'm working on Java web application and using from `Maven Build Configuration` and `Weblogic` as a web server.

When i build the project, build complete successfully but when i start `Oracle Weblogic WebServer`, the files that created during build in `target` folder, getting to deleted!!

Comment: How are you deploying your application?

Comment: Can you build an ear and deploy it or use weblogic.deploy? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13702/deploy.htm#i1031459